# Javascript: event.target.id undefined in event listener

Tags: javascript, for-loop, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to add event listeners for multiple divs in a for loop:

```
var divElements = document.getElementsByClassName('B');
var vMax = divElements.length;
for (var i = 0; i < vMax; i += 1) {
    divElements[i].addEventListener('DOMCharacterDataModified', function(e) {
        myFunc(e.target);
    }, false);
}

function myFunc(elem) {
    var text = elem.textContent;
    var id = elem.id;
    console.log("text: " + text);
    console.log("id: " + id);
}
```

Problem with this code is, that although the `text` is OK and correct text is in it, `id` variable is undefined, although the element has id set in html. Is this code OK or am I missing something?

I also tried `e.target.getAttribute("id")` but it ends up with `e.target.getAttribute is not a function` error.

Comment: `document.getElementById("A").getElementsByClassName('B')` doesn't make much sense since `.getElementById()` will only return one element (if there is a match) and, if there is a match, then the class name doesn't matter. You are doing all this extra DOM querying and looping when all you need to do is get the element by its `id` and then add an event listener directly to it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It doesn't matter in this example, the result is the same. I just needed to select child divs. I deleted it from the question so  it's not confusing.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML so that we can try to reproduce your issue and provide a working answer. Also include what you are doing to trigger the event.

Comment: You should also know that `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a "live" node list that requires that the query be carried out every time you access the variable associated with the node list. As a result it's very expensive to use, especially in a loop. Instead, use `.querySelectorAll()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that a text node is node that is created as an implicit child node of most element nodes. You are trying to get the `id` of the parent element node of the text node in question, but `elem` is a child of that node, so you have to access `elem.parentNode.id`.

We can see this by examining the `nodeType` and `nodeName` properties of the different nodes.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)**:

- Element Nodes have a node type of **1**
- Text Nodes have a node type of     **3**

```js
var div = document.getElementById("A");
div.addEventListener('DOMCharacterDataModified', function(e) {
  console.log("Target element is a " + e.target.nodeName + " node and has a node type of: " + e.target.nodeType);
  console.log("Target element.parentNode is a " + e.target.parentNode.nodeName + 
               " node and has a node type of: " + e.target.parentNode.nodeType);

  console.log("Target element.text: " + e.target.textContent);
  console.log("Target element.parentNode.id: " + e.target.parentNode.id);
});
```

```html
<h1>Click into the text below and modify it somehow:</h1>
<div id="A" contenteditable>Something</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the parameter being passed into myFunc to be the div that you are assigning the handler to, so just replace `e.target` with `this` in the function call.

```js
var divElements = document.getElementsByClassName('B');
var vMax = divElements.length;
for (var i = 0; i < vMax; i += 1) {
    divElements[i].addEventListener(
      'DOMCharacterDataModified', 
      function(e) {
        myFunc(this);
      },
      false
    );
}

function myFunc(elem) {
    var text = elem.textContent;
    var id = elem.id;
    console.log("text: " + text);
    console.log("id: " + id);
}
```

```html
<div class='B' id='p1' contenteditable>part 1</div>
<div class='B' id='p2' contenteditable>part 2</div>
<div class='B' id='p3' contenteditable>part 3</div>
```